# Upload file to server using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, file, server, upload

I have a problem loading the file to the server in PHP and HTML using move_uploaded_file () when I put PHP files in this way http://mydomin.com/uploadfile.php succeed the process and if this way http://mydomin.com/uploadfiles/uploadfile.php The the process fails

code php

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {

    $idApp = uniqid();
    $uploadDir = '../images/';
    $uploadedFile = $uploadDir . $idApp . ".jpg";

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)) {

    echo"Success: ".$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']. $uploadedFile;
    } else {

    echo"error 2";
    }

} else {

    echo"error 3";
}
?>
```

code html

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type='file' name='image' id='image'>
    <div align='center''><input type='submit' id='myButton' value='add'></div>";

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your upload path

```
$uploadDir = '../images/';
```

Try to use this path './images/' or best use absolute path.

Comment: Not working with me, but how to use the absolute path

Comment: The file in which my site is "/website/" and the file in which the PHP files upload the image in "/website/uploadfiles/ "and want to upload in "/website/images" I have used this code and succeeded the process ( $uploadDir = '../../website/images/';)

Comment: you can try __FILE__ it will return a absolute path of the current file.

Answer (score 1):

check your script location by using

```
var_dump(__DIR__)
```

this will show you where is your .php file is ( also called as absolute path ). Thus simply you can see where you made a mistake to assign a folder for file uploading(image in your case ).